Txt file to dataframe by row and column
I have a dataset which is in a txt.file but when i read it using pandas it gets into one colunm.
for example:
FSXC_20129_2024120000.txt
1017.0    18   26.6   15.6     51  11.07        
1000.0   157   25.0   14.0     50  10.14      
1983.1   305   23.8   13.2     52   9.80      
2949.2   610   21.3   11.6     54   9.11       
1925.0   835   19.4   10.4     56   8.63   

its read as using pandas and converting into df the columns are one but i need it to be seperate row by column and also to add the headers to each columns eg, ID_1, ID_2, ID_3, etc.
your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

[ask] and [mre]

You can use delim_whitespace to load whitespace or tab separated ".txt" into pandas dataframe and assign column names. Sample code is as follows:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("FSXC_20129_2024120000.txt", delim_whitespace=True)
col_name = [f"ID_{i+1}" for i in range(df.shape[1])]
df.columns = col_name
df.head(2)


Code
import io
import pandas as pd
txt = '''FSXC_20129_2024120000.txt
1017.0    18   26.6   15.6     51  11.07        
1000.0   157   25.0   14.0     50  10.14      
1983.1   305   23.8   13.2     52   9.80      
2949.2   610   21.3   11.6     54   9.11       
1925.0   835   19.4   10.4     56   8.63  
'''
df = (pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt), sep='\s+', skiprows=1, header=None)
        .rename(columns=lambda x: f'ID_{x + 1}')
)

df:
     ID_1  ID_2  ID_3  ID_4  ID_5   ID_6
0  1017.0    18  26.6  15.6    51  11.07
1  1000.0   157  25.0  14.0    50  10.14
2  1983.1   305  23.8  13.2    52   9.80
3  2949.2   610  21.3  11.6    54   9.11
4  1925.0   835  19.4  10.4    56   8.63

you can replace io.StringIO(txt) to your file path.
